# Deployment Stopped working suddenly and Ultimo Theme Layout Breaks

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.2.7

I am using magento 2.2.7 and everything was working fine since long time but 
suddenly deploy stop and on frontend css not loading and entire layout miss match also getting error while i am running deploy command 
Error :

```
#0 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(73): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(61): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publishAsset(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#2 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticFile.php(92): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publish(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#3 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(189): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticFile->deployFile('images/infortis...', Array)
#4 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(136): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->processFile(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\PackageFile), Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#5 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(107): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deployEmulated(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array, false)
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->Magento\Deploy\Service\{closure}()
#7 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php(186): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#8 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/State/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode('frontend', Object(Closure), Array)
#9 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(108): Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor->emulateAreaCode('frontend', Object(Closure))
#10 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(300): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deploy(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array)
#11 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(219): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->execute(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#12 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(162): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->assertAndExecute('frontend/Infort...', Array, Array)
#13 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Strategy/QuickDeploy.php(76): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->process()
#14 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticContent.php(109): Magento\Deploy\Strategy\QuickDeploy->deploy(Array)
#15 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentCommand.php(140): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent->deploy(Array)
#16 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(245): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(835): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(185): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(102): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#22 {main}
#0 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(73): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(61): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publishAsset(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#2 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticFile.php(92): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publish(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#3 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(189): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticFile->deployFile('images/infortis...', Array)
#4 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(136): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->processFile(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\PackageFile), Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#5 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(107): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deployEmulated(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array, false)
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->Magento\Deploy\Service\{closure}()
#7 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php(186): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#8 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/State/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode('frontend', Object(Closure), Array)
#9 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(108): Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor->emulateAreaCode('frontend', Object(Closure))
#10 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(300): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deploy(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array)
#11 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(219): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->execute(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#12 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/sites/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(162): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->assertAndExecute('frontend/Infort...', Array, Array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. `rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/`
2. `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
3. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` <-- use -f and --theme Vendor/Theme if you have a specific theme in place

Comment: non of this working

Comment: @NavinBhudiya Is there anything useful in any of the magento logs? What were you doing right before this issue started?

Answer (score 0):

An error was due to database issue so we revert to old database backup and all working perfectly